# Regular expression in C++ throwing error "Invalid special open parenthesis."

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I am currently dealing with a query like this:

a.b.c.d.e~f

and I am trying to extract a,b,c,d,e and f.

I've made some progress extracting period separated values, but I am still stuck as it seems as though the special query I have for extracting the last element (prepended by the tilde "~") with the PCRE `(?<=~).*`, as it fails at run-time.

I am getting a pretty unique error (at least according to google) which is "

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  Invalid special open parenthesis.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {  
  const string example = "a.b.c~height";

  regex regex_query_path(R"rgx([^.]+(?=[^~]*~))rgx");

  std::smatch m;
  string test = example;
  while (std::regex_search (test,m,regex_query_path)) {
    cout << "path: " << m[0] << endl;
    test = m.suffix().str();
  }

  regex regex_query_name(R"rgx((?<=~).*)rgx");

  test = example;
  while (std::regex_search (test,m,regex_query_name)) {
    cout << "query: " << m[0] << endl;
    test = m.suffix().str();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and I am compiling it with g++ -std=c++14 and gcc version 6.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.08.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure it out? I also encountered this error for std::regex("(?:^|,)(?=[^\"]|(\")?)\"?((?(1)[^\"]*|[^,\"]*))\"?(?=,|$)")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use parentheses, you need to escape them with a backslash.

Here is an example:

```
std::string regexstring = "\\([a-z]\\):\\([0-9]\\)";
```

Comment: He's not trying to match parens, but do groups.