# regex_replace invalid open parenthesis

Tags: c++, regex

[DEMO](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/9enCExFEa)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>    

int main() {
    
    std::wstring str = LR"(
        
           bst.enable_adb_access="1"
           
           )";
           
    std::wregex re(L"(?<=bst\\.enable_adb_access.*?)\\d+");
    
    str = std::regex_replace(str, re, L"0");
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
}
```

error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
> what():  Invalid special open parenthesis.

https://regex101.com/r/a33eFL/1

Whats wrong with the parenthesis?

Comment: The [default regex flavour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript#Assertions) in C++ understands lookaheads only, lookbehinds do not work. Not sure if POSIX, awk or grep flavours accept lookbehinds, unfortunately cppreference doesn't specify them on its own.

Comment: And how the linked quest can help which my problem?

Comment: I've reopened the question. While https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118813/regular-expression-in-c-throwing-error-invalid-special-open-parenthesis?noredirect=1&lq=1 is the same question really, the answer there is incorrect, so I treat it as having no answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a lookbehind for this situation. Simply use a normal capturing group and include it in the replacement string:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>    
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    std::wstring str = LR"(
 
           bst.enable_adb_access="1"
 
           )";
 
    std::wregex re(L"(bst\\.enable_adb_access.*?)\\d+");
 
    str = std::regex_replace(str, re, L"$010");
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
           bst.enable_adb_access="0"
```

Note that because the substitution for the capturing group is followed by a digit, we need to use the `$nn` format for the group number (hence `$010`), otherwise `$10` *could* - dependent on the compiler - be interpreted as replacing with capture group 10.

[Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/yOvlgk)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one illustration why the plural of "regex" is "regrets"...

C++ accepts several flavours of regexes, but none of them seems to understand lookbehinds. Default [modified ECMAScript](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript#Assertions) flavour only accepts lookaheads. I'm not 100% sure about POSIX, awk and grep flavours, but none of them seems to have any lookarounds whatsoever.

Fortunately, you can get the same effect without lookarounds, using capturing group. I had to change format string rules to sed, because default ECMAScript rules allow for two-digit backreferences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>    

int main() {
    
    std::wstring str = LR"(
        
           bst.enable_adb_access="1"
           
           )";
           
    std::wregex re(L"(bst\\.enable_adb_access.*?)\\d+");
    
    str = std::regex_replace(str, re, L"\\10", std::regex_constants::format_sed);
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
}
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/zK6xdjaxM)

Comment: Good idea using the sed format to get around the whole group numbering issue.